# select the rows that satisfy the same condition on all columns

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an array of data called **`d`** with the shape of `(79000,17)`. I am wondering whether there is a way to write a short loop or a function that enforce a condition to all columns to choose just rows where they satisfy the same condition on the columns, if for instance a loop which combine the condition for column `i`, `d[:,i]<99`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a flexible select function that support all conditions (even your condition), you can use below code. Implement my_filter() as you want.

```
def select(list_of_rows, filter_function):
    result = []
    for row in list_of_rows:
        if filter_function(row):
            result.append(row)
    return result

def my_filter(row):
    if row[2] > 10:
        return True
    return False

my_list = [(1, 4, 7), (2, 9, 12), (4, 2, 20), (10, 20, 30), (3, 2, 1)]
result = select(my_list, my_filter)
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your answer, the condition can be checked element-wise
and then you could apply `all` reduction across column axis (i.e.
find rows where elements in all columns, columns are `axis=1`,
are `True`)

```
In [15]: arr = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5); arr
Out[15]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

In [16]: ((arr > 7) & (arr < 17)).astype(int)
Out[16]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0]], dtype=bool)

In [17]: ((arr > 7) & (arr < 17)).all(axis=1)
Out[17]: array([False, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

If the condition is really a column-wise function, you can use
`np.apply_along_axis` to slice your array by row axis, `axis=0`, apply
that function to all slices and then use the same all reduction on the
output:

```
In [38]: def between_multiples_of_2(x):
    return ((x % 2) == 0).cumsum() == 1
   ....: 

In [39]: np.apply_along_axis(between_multiples_of_2, axis=0, arr=arr).astype(int)
Out[39]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [40]: np.apply_along_axis(between_multiples_of_2, axis=0, arr=arr).all(axis=1)
Out[40]: array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

First make a `Boolean` array with the size of the number of rows and then compute the condition each time in a loop and multiply it with the initial Boolean array.

```
import numpy as np
bx=np.ones(d.shape[0], dtype=bool)

for i in range(d.shape[1]):
    bx*=((d[:,i]>17)*(d[:,i]<22.0))
```